# Differentials in index notation

Tags: tensor-calculus, differentiation, calculus

I'm trying to show the following

$$
\frac12 F_{\sigma\beta}\frac{\partial F_{\sigma\beta}}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\alpha)} = F_{\mu\alpha}
$$

where the EM field tensor $F_{\sigma\alpha} = \partial_\sigma A_\beta - \partial_\beta A_\sigma$ (from Zangwill on EM).

Substituting in, I've got as far as
$$
\partial_\sigma A_\beta \frac{\partial (\partial_\sigma A_\beta)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\alpha)} - \partial_\sigma A_\beta \frac{\partial (\partial_\beta A_\sigma)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\alpha)} = \partial_\mu A_\alpha - \partial_\alpha A_\mu
$$
which seems to imply
$$
\frac{\partial (\partial_\sigma A_\beta)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\alpha)} = \delta_{\sigma\mu}\delta_{\alpha\beta}
$$
is that right? If so, why? With the derivative in the bottom of the differential I'm not really sure where to go

Comment: A question is how did you arrive at the answer by not using that relationship?

Answer (score 3):

It may help to put the notation $\frac{\partial (\partial_\sigma A_\rho)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)}$ on a firmer footing.  That collection of symbols is really a shorthand abuse of notation in the following sense.

Let's say we have a function $f$ which eats $3$ real numbers and spits out a real number. $f$ has $3$ partial derivatives $\partial_1 f,\partial_2 f,\partial_3 f$ corresponding to differentiation with respect to each entry.  If we call its inputs $(a,b,c)$, then it is common to write
$$(\partial_1f\big)(a,b,c) \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\qquad (\partial_2f\big)(a,b,c) \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\qquad (\partial_3f\big)(a,b,c) \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial c} \qquad (\star)$$

This is elementary calculus.  But now let's say I have some function $T$ which eats two real numbers $(x,y)$ and I decide to plug it and its derivatives into the slots of $f$:
$$f\bigg(T,\partial_xT, \partial_yT\bigg)$$

If I follow the convention in $(\star)$, then I would obtain
$$ \big(\partial_2f\big)(T,\partial_xT,\partial_yT) \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial(\partial_x T)}$$

Anytime you see something like $\partial(\partial_x T)$ in the bottom of an expression, this is what you're really doing; you're differentiating a function with respect to a slot *and then* plugging $(\partial_x T)$ into that slot.

---

Now imagine we let $f(a,b,c)=b$.  Then we would have $f(T,\partial_x T,\partial_y T) = \partial_x T$, and
$$\big(\partial_1f\big)(T,\partial_xT,\partial_yT) \equiv \frac{\partial (\partial_xT)}{\partial( T)} = 0$$
$$\big(\partial_2f\big)(T,\partial_xT,\partial_yT) \equiv \frac{\partial (\partial_x T)}{\partial(\partial_x T)} = 1$$
$$\big(\partial_3f\big)(T,\partial_xT,\partial_yT) \equiv \frac{\partial (\partial_xT)}{\partial(\partial_y T)} = 0$$

This is fundamentally what we mean when we write something like $\frac{\partial(\partial_\sigma A_\rho)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\nu)} = \delta_\sigma^\mu \delta_\nu^\rho$. It is a significant abuse of notation, but the alternative is probably worse; if we have $n$ fields $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ and $m$ coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$, then a Lagrangian which depends on the fields and their first derivatives would have $(m+1)n$ slots (for electromagnetism in $(3+1)$-dimensions, that would be 20).   Trying to use the slot notation $\partial_1 f, \ldots, \partial_{20}f$ while keeping track of which derivative of which field goes into which slot is an unappealing concept.

Answer (score 1):

The last relation is indeed correct. It is just by definition by treating the $\partial_\mu A_\nu$ as independent fields. For the remaining part note that:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial F_{\sigma \beta}}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)} = \delta_{\sigma}^\mu \delta_{\nu}^{\beta} - \delta_{\sigma}^{\nu}\delta_{\mu }^{\beta}.
\end{equation}

Comment: great, so $\partial X_{ab} / \partial X_{yz} = \delta_a^y \delta_b^z$ is just an identity?

Answer (score 1):

ACarter, I had the same doubt. Here's how I got around it.

When you calculate

$$
\frac{\partial(\partial_\sigma A_\beta)}{\partial(\partial_\mu A_\alpha)}
$$

you are differentiating *with respect to* $\partial_\mu A_\alpha$, i.e. as if it were a variable in 1d Calc. The thing is that you have 16 different cases for each value $ \mu $ and $ \nu $ can take. For example one element of the tensor above is:

$$
\frac{\partial(\partial_1 A_0)}{\partial(\partial_0 A_1)}
$$

However, in this case, that is equal to zero, because it is obviously not the same "variable". The case above is like taking the partial derivative of $ f = y $ w.r.t $x$ in  3d. Thus, you have to introduce the kroenecker deltas to remind yourself that if the top and bottom are not the same, in terms of subindices, then the derivative is zero.